# ASP MVC 4: OutOfMemoryExecption error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Please help me I'm having an error with this line of code in my mvcController.cs :

```
    public ActionResult MEMORY()
    {


        WardenEntities d = new WardenEntities();
        return View(d.BlockingHistories.ToList().Take(3));//
    }
```

Please click the links to see the error and my .cshtml file where I call the controller:
http://animobile.info/upload/1/Capture1.PNG

http://animobile.info/upload/1/Capture.PNG or Capture3.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this instead.  Your version returns all rows from the table into memory, then takes 3 of them.  You want to only take 3, then put them in the list.

```
return View(d.BlockingHistories.Take(3).ToList());
```

Comment: Ohh thank you so much Mr. @Erik Funkenbusch. I'm sorry for the noob question I'm new with ASP mvc :D